# What is a Scanning Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>Based on the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion),</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Scanning Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Scanning Words™ | Not Scanning Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| SECT | BLANK |
| QUIP | SWEAT |
| WET | SEEN |
| DRIP | LUMP |
| SCRUM | RAM |
| DRY | BEER |
| AIL | PINES |
| THUMP | STINK |
| DRUM | FAIL |
| BUMP | HEAL |

<sub>[(image archive)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QotjX.png)</sub>

CSV version:

```
Scanning Words™,Not Scanning Words™
SECT,BLANK
QUIP,SWEAT
WET,SEEN
DRIP,LUMP
SCRUM,RAM
DRY,BEER
AIL,PINES
THUMP,STINK
DRUM,FAIL
BUMP,HEAL
```

And no, it is not the font.

---

<sub>This is my first try on [What is a Word™/Phrase™,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) please let me know on how to improve.</sub>

Comment: Just to point out, that is not CSV.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A Scanning Word™ is a word that

> is typed strictly from left to right on a standard QWERTY keyboard layout (in roughly hexagonal key positions). SCRUM disambiguates the very close C and R, which allows us to infer the correct order. SEEN suggests that repeated letters are disallowed. More precisely, any subsequence of "QAZWSXEDCRFVTGBYHNUJMIKOLP".